# Bootstrap3 navigation toggle not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I've built a test site based using Bootstrap3, however the toggle doesn't work and I can't find any errors. The JS script is installed correctly and I've added the code to the functions file linking to the `WP_nav_walker` file available on GitHub. The header file code is:

```
   <?php
   wp_nav_menu( array(
   'menu' => 'primary',
   'theme_location' => 'primary',
   'depth' => 2,
  'container' => 'div',
  'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
   'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
   'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
   'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
   );
    ?>
```

And I've added this to the functions doc:

```
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

connecting to wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php
```

Site link [here](http://creative-media.info/WarringtonBonsai/).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your link to your JS file is wrong.

http://creative-media.info/WarringtonBonsai/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)

When you add your script, be sure to use

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(),     '1.0.0', true );
```

Actually, it tries to find your script in an other folder then your theme folder.